# Sequelize ORM include model only if active = true

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

how can I findAll orders with id: 1 and include items only if this item has active = true? Otherwise there will be empty array...

```
Order.findAll({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: [
      { model: Item, where: sequelize.and({'active' : true }) }
    ]
}).then(function(order) {
    callback(null, order);
});
```

This shows me only orders where are some items with active = true. I wanted to show all orders with id: 1 and items as a sub-array ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Sequelize Tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findandcountall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database-returns-both-data-and-total-count):

> Adding a where clause to the include automatically makes it required

The solution is this:

```
Order.findAll({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: [
      { model: Item, 
        where: sequelize.and({'active' : true }),
        required: false 
      }
    ]
}).then(function(order) {
    callback(null, order);
});
```